# ArrayList Java - Sobrescrevendo os valores

Tags: java, array

Galera preciso realizar a seguinte atividade:

*"Considere uma aplicação para armazenar os seguintes dados de uma pessoa em uma agenda de endereços: nome, endereço e telefone. Especifique um TAD para armazenar os dados das pessoas e as operações necessárias para inserir, consultar e excluir os dados das pessoas."*

Bom, preciso criar uma classe que registre um usuário e realize operações como consultar registro e exclusão, bom, sou leigo em java mas consegui gravar os dados em um ArrayList, entretanto sempre que registro um usuário novo, o anterior é sobrescrito, armazenando apenas o último cadastrado. Abaixo está o código, dividido em classe Main, Pessoa e Operações. Quero saber o porque está sobrescrevendo e se o código em geral está de acordo com o enunciado da questão. Agradeço a todos!

Classe Main:

```
public class exercicio {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Pessoa usuario = new Pessoa();
    Operacoes acao = new Operacoes();

    int op;

    do {
        System.out.println("[1] Inserir");
        System.out.println("[2] Consultar");
        System.out.println("[3] Remover");
        System.out.println("[4] Sair");
        System.out.print("Opção desejada: ");
        op = input.nextInt();
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Nome: ");
                usuario.setNome(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Endereço: ");
                usuario.setEndereco(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Telefone: ");
                usuario.setTelefone(input.nextLine());
                acao.inserePessoa(usuario);
                System.out.println(usuario);
                break;
            case 2:
                acao.consultaPessoa();
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 4);
}}
```

Classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {

String nome;
String endereco;
String telefone;

public Pessoa() {
}

public Pessoa(String nome, String endereco, String telefone) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.endereco = endereco;
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}

public String getEndereco() {
    return endereco;
}

public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
    this.endereco = endereco;
}

public String getTelefone() {
    return telefone;
}

public void setTelefone(String telefone) {
    this.telefone = telefone;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "nome=" + nome + ", endereco=" + endereco + ", telefone=" + telefone;
}}
```

Classe Operações:

```
public class Operacoes extends Pessoa {

ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoa = new ArrayList<>();

public void inserePessoa(Object usuario) {
    listaPessoa.add((Pessoa) usuario);
}

public String consultaPessoa() {
    for (Pessoa c: listaPessoa) {
        System.out.println(listaPessoa.get(0));
    }
    return "oi";
}}
```

Comment: por que você coloca  usuario como Object ?

Comment: E como eu faria isso? Qual a diferença?

Comment: "tudo é um objeto", esse objeto só pode ser pessoa, então você colocar Pessoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar novas instancias desse objeto Pessoa que você criou

```
public class exercicio {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Operacoes acao = new Operacoes();

    int op;

    do {
        System.out.println("[1] Inserir");
        System.out.println("[2] Consultar");
        System.out.println("[3] Remover");
        System.out.println("[4] Sair");
        System.out.print("Opção desejada: ");
        op = input.nextInt();
        switch (op) {
            case 1:
                Pessoa usuario = new Pessoa();
                input.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Nome: ");
                usuario.setNome(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Endereço: ");
                usuario.setEndereco(input.nextLine());
                System.out.print("Telefone: ");
                usuario.setTelefone(input.nextLine());
                acao.inserePessoa(usuario);
                System.out.println(usuario);
                break;
            case 2:
                acao.consultaPessoa();
                break;
            case 3:
                break;
        }
    } while (op != 4);
}}
```

acesse a lista com this.

```
public class Operacoes extends Pessoa {

public ArrayList<Pessoa> listaPessoa = new ArrayList<>();

public void inserePessoa(Pessoa usuario) {
    listaPessoa.add(usuario);
}

public String consultaPessoa() {
    for (Pessoa c: this.listaPessoa) {
        System.out.println(listaPessoa.get(0));
    }
    return "oi";
}}
```

Se você quer remover uma Pessoa pelo nome

```
public String deletaPessoa(String alvo) {
    for (Pessoa c: this.listaPessoa) {
       if (c.getnome().equals(alvo)) c.remove();
    }

}
```

Essa imagem ilustra isso, em vez de pessoa com arvores
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Cada pessoa é alguém diferente, tem uma Id diferente, se você alterar a mesma instancia, está alterando a mesma pessoa

Comment: Certo, realizei a alteração, instanciando cada pessoa como um objeto diferente, entretanto a consulta ainda retorna o ultimo registro cadastrado. Como faço para percorrer todos os dados do arraylist?

Comment: Você está acessando ela diretamente, coloque como public static e this. na hora no for, olhe como ficou resposta agora

Comment: Deu certinho, mas sem querer abusar muito, como eu realizaria a remoção de um determinado registro? Eu teria que cadastrar junto com nome, endereço e telefone um código identificador?

Comment: Se você achar que a resposta te ajudou vote, se estar certa marque como certa (:

Comment: ajudou sim, marquei também. Teria como me ajudar na minha outra questão?

Comment: Cria outra pergunta que estou monitorando

Comment: concordo plenamente, evito ao máximo tocar na estrutura na hora de tirar duvidas, somente, não sei se isso é a melhor forma de responder, penso que teria que mudar 80% codigo/modelagem para ficar algo na semântica do java

Comment: mgibsonbr, sou estudante inciante de Java, teria alguma rede social, ou algum contato mais direto que possa me explicar um pouquinho sobre o que você disse, ou fica difícil?

Comment: @mgibsonbr, Verdade... na pergunta dele, ele esteva acessando de forma estática, eu corrigi colocando o static e coloquei o this no for, ficou meio sem sentido mesmo.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, testei agora no eclipse, não funciona não, pode ser que tenha funcionamento diferente entre versões do java

DanLucio, você encontra esses conceitos bem detalhados nesse livro [Java Book](http://www.casadocodigo.com.br/products/livro-certificacao-java-associate)

Comment: Gente, como utilizamos o chat do overflow, vamos discutir sobre isso, tendo duas pessoas com um bom entendimento é ótimo para um aluno.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21538/discussion-between-isvaldo-fernandes-and-dan-lucio-prada).